# How to convert a simple SQL join query to HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have this query that I need in HQL, but I have found very little help online.

```
select first_name, last_name, group_id, group_name, status
from users
join groups on groups.id = users.group_id
```

What would this be if converted to HQL?

Comment: Did you looked up the some hql example queries?

Comment: Its better to go for mapping in your groups or users  pojo like onetomany and you are done.

Comment: Yeah i've looked up loads of them but none of them seemed very applicable due to the database i'm ussing, if you have any good links to examples i'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Making a few assumptions:

```
select u.first_name, u.last_name, u.group.id, u.group.group_name, u.group.status
from users u
```

Basically the join is done for you. You just reference other objects in the object graph using dot notation.

Comment: that's brilliant thanks, do you know any sites that are good at explaining the differences between the two?

Comment: Any tool / plugin with eclipse, to confirm the HQL created is accurate.. ? anyone have any idea.. ?